# Backing up Google Cloud Storage to another Bucket

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I know there are cronjob's available to backup google datastore but are there any easy methods of creating a cronjob to make daily backups of Google Cloud Storage to another Cloud Storage bucket?

I know I could use something like this:

```
gsutil cp -D -R gs://<bucket>/* gs://<backup>/folder
```

Or I've ready something about [Object Versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) but not sure if this pertains to what I am trying to do.

But I'd like to do this in a cronjob using a php appengine and not in a compute engine.

I know I can create objects like so: (but is there a way to easily migrate and copy data over?)

```
$document_data = "123456789";
$object_url = "gs://<bucket>/file.ext";
$options = stream_context_create(['gs'=>['acl'=>'private']]);
$my_file = fopen($object_url, 'w', false, $options);
fwrite($my_file, $document_data);
fclose($my_file);
```

Comment: Have you looked at [`gsutil rsync`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync)?

Comment: I'm iffy on whether I want to do that or not. I'd rather have daily backups. @tx802

Answer (score 12):

A little bit late eh, but [GCS Transfer](https://console.cloud.google.com/transfer/cloud) is what you are looking for.

From the doc:

> Transfer data to your Cloud Storage buckets from Amazon Simple Storage
> Service (S3), HTTP/HTTPS servers, or other buckets. You can schedule
> one-time or daily transfers, and you can filter files based on name
> prefix and when they were changed.

Comment: I hope the OP comes back and marks this as the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is not an equivalent automated GCS tool like datastore's backup/restore tool. A cronjob running on a GCE instance, like you identified, is the easiest way to accomplish such a task.

Object versioning may suit your needs depending on why you want a backup. Object versioning works by keeping multiple copies of an object such that every time you overwrite or delete an object, its previous state stays around as an object with the same name but a different "generation" number. You can also configure Google Cloud Storage to periodically delete generations older than a certain amount of time or with a certain number of later generations already existing.

That may be fine if your big worry is accidentally overwriting important data. Or it might not be fine if you're worried about accidentally deleting all of the objects in your bucket, including older generations of objects. Or it might not be fine if you need the ability to reset your bucket to the state of a particular day.

If object versioning doesn't work for you, and you don't want to set up a cronjob running gsutil, and you want to use app engine, then yes, you'd have to write a program that iterates over all of the objects in your bucket and copies them to another bucket.

Comment: When you say "set up a cronjob running gsutil" you mean, setting a cronjob running a script that calls compute engine that runs gsutil correct? I am not away of any cronjob functions that run gsutil directly.

Comment: That would work, but I meant setting up a crontab entry on the GCE host itself specifying that exact gsutil line.

Answer (score 0):

To copy everything in a source bucket to a destination bucket, you could use a command similar to this:

```
$ gsutil cp -r gs://SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME/* gs://DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME/
```

Alternatively you could use gsutil rsync with the -r switch to synchronise the contents of a source bucket with a destination bucket. For example:

```
$ gsutil rsync -r gs://SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME gs://DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME/
```

[reference](https://serverfault.com/a/899332/491178)